# typescript incorrectly narrows the type

Tags: typescript

In this example:

```
let x: string|null = null;
["test"].forEach(si => {
    x = si;
})
x
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBDOYBOBLAdgcwD5oK7GAgF4I8CBuAWACgBtAIjBEXoF0A6AMwHskBRAIYBjABYAKeCmIA+CAG8aEJdGIIUVagF8AlDShA)

typescript infers `x` at the end of code to be of type `null`. I don't understand how come it has narrowed the type from its initial `string|null`?

If I run this code in node:

```js
let x = null;
["test"].forEach((si) => {
  x = si;
});
console.log(x);
```

the output is `test`, therefore the type `null` seems incorrect?

It seems to have something to do with the lambdas, because using `for..of` for the loop correctly gives a final type of `string|null`. I guess typescript cannot check what's going on in the closures? But if it doesn't know, why narrow the type instead of leaving it to its original `string|null`?

Comment: Design limitation. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: the issue says basically that the system is heuristic based and may guess wrongly in both directions (narrow when it shouldn't or the opposite). I understand that it cannot be conservative because then it'd miss many useful cases. So it sees a lambda and assumes it won't overwrite the variable... And I guess there are no markers we could put in the code to work around it.. We'd need a `as` or to rework the code... I guess.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding lambdas (or any functions) which assign to non-local variables; if you really need a function to modify some external state, you could encapsulate this state in an object instead of a closure. Alternatively, you could pass the needed state explicitly as a parameter and a return value, which is essentially how `reduce` differs from `forEach`.